# Openstack Queens installation issue (network.pp/puppet error)

Tags: centos, puppet, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

I am installing Openstack (Queens) using Packstack. When I install components of Openstack, I am getting the following error continuously:

192.168.122.x.y_network.pp:                        [ ERROR ]
Applying Puppet manifests                         [ ERROR ]

ERROR : Error appeared during Puppet run: 192.168.x.y_network.pp
Error: /Stage[main]/Packstack::Provision::Bridge/Neutron_l3_ovs_bridge[demo_bridge]: Could not evaluate: Can't retrieve subnet-list because Neutron or Keystone API is not available.

Could you please help me out on how to proceed further? I have tried almost every documentation on the net.

PS : I am running Openstack on a CentOS 7 Virtual Machine.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the command/action you used to install which triggered this issue

Comment: @Qwertie 1. sudo yum install -y centos-release-openstack-queens  2. sudo yum update -y  3.  sudo yum install -y openstack-packstack  4. sudo packstack --allinone  5. sudo yum install openstack-utils       After running these, i run an answerfile that I generated.